# Add language annotation after opening ```

Tags: regex, vim

Suppose such a text

````
```
find ~ -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*/[^/]{3,}.pdf'
```

You should also escape the `.` so that it matches “.” rather than any character:

```
find ~ -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*/[^/]{3,}\.pdf'
```

The regular expression can be simplified since we only care about three non-“/” characters:

```
find ~ -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*[^/]{3}\.pdf'
```
````

[image]

I'd like to add language annotation to the opening ```

if come with python, it's easy to implement with

````
import re
re.sub(r"```([^`]+)```, r```bash\1```, text)
````

How could apply such a regex within vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in vim, you can do:

````
%s/\v(^```)(\_.{-}```)/\1bash\2/g
````

This requires that the

````
```
````

are paired. (same as your python sub)

Comment: amazing, could you please recommend an tutorial on vim regex, I found [Vim Regular Expressions 101](http://www.vimregex.com/), but it is not very good.

Comment: @JawSaw I don't know which tutorial is good, but you can start from `:h regex` I guess.